# Can I remove the Dolby Atmos advert from Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

A recent Windows update (I am running Windows 10 build 1803) is soliciting me for money via my volume icon. I don't approve of any form of advertising on the machine and Operating System I paid for and I want to remove it.
Here is the advert:

[image]

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise so hopefully there is a GPO or something I can set.
If anyone has any ideas I'll be glad to try and report back.

Comment: Try right-click and uninstall.

Comment: Right-click _what_

Comment: The "Dolby ATMOS" icon in the start menu. Or uninstall it from the store.

Comment: It's not installed. That's why Windows is showing me an ad for it.

Comment: That can be removed. The option should be also in the right-click menu.

Comment: Where did my last comment go? I'll say it again: this is a context menu, you can't right-click a context menu. If you know where this "remove" option is, please offer the information as an answer, because your instructions so far have been impossible to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Statement from Dolby:

As part of an agreement between Microsoft and Dolby, all versions of Windows 10 Fall Creators edition and later will feature the Dolby Atmos for Headphones option in the audio spatial sound settings.  The option to choose Dolby Atmos for Headphones is hard-coded into the OS and will always be there regardless if the app is installed or not.  When you see this option and you have not installed the actual app from the MS Store, no software is actually installed on your system.  If you did install Dolby Atmos for Headphones but decided to uninstall it, you will still see the option in your spatial sound settings but you can safely ignore it if you will not be using it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide proper attribution (link) to your source for this.

Comment: I'm fine with the _option_ to use Dolby Atmos if it's part of the OS, but I just want the  "Try or buy from the Store" menu-item removed. There must be a Group Policy setting for this.